# Highlight on ElasticSearch autocomplete

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following data to be indexed on ElasticSearch.

[image]

I want to implement an autocomplete feature, and highlight why a specific document matched a query.

This are the settings of my index:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1, 
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "autocomplete_filter": { 
                    "type":     "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 15
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "autocomplete": {
                    "type":      "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "autocomplete_filter" 
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index Analyzing**

- Splits text on word boundaries.
- Removes pontuation.
- Lowercases
- Edge NGrams each token

So the Inverted Index looks like:

[image]

This is how i defined the mappings for a name field:

```
{
    "index_type": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type":     "string",
                "index_analyzer":  "autocomplete", 
                "search_analyzer": "standard" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I query:

```
GET http://localhost:9200/index/type/_search

{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name": "soft"
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "fields" : {
            "name" : {}
        }
    }
}
```

**Search for: *soft***

Applying the Standard Tokenizer, the "soft" is the term, to find on the inverted index. This search matches the Documents: 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 which is correct, but the highlighted part I would expect to be "soft" and not the whole word:

```
{
  "hits": [
    {
      "_source": {
        "name": "SoftwareRocks everytime"
      },
      "highlight": {
        "name": [
          "<em>SoftwareRocks</em> everytime"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "_source": {
        "name": "Software AG"
      },
      "highlight": {
        "name": [
          "<em>Software</em> AG"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "_source": {
        "name": "Software AG2"
      },
      "highlight": {
        "name": [
          "<em>Software</em> AG2"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "_source": {
        "name": "Op Software AG good software better"
      },
      "highlight": {
        "name": [
          "Op <em>Software</em> AG good <em>software</em> better"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "_source": {
        "name": "Op Software AG"
      },
      "highlight": {
        "name": [
          "Op <em>Software</em> AG"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "_source": {
        "name": "is soft ware ok"
      },
      "highlight": {
        "name": [
          "is <em>soft</em> ware ok"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Search for: *software ag***

Applying the Standard Tokenizer, the "software ag" is transformed into "software" and "ag", to find on the inverted index. This search matches the Documents: 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, which is correct, but the highlighted part I would expect to be "software" and "ag" and not the whole word around "software" and "ag":

```
{
  "hits": [
    {
      "_source": {
        "name": "Software AG"
      },
      "highlight": {
        "name": [
          "<em>Software</em> <em>AG</em>"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "_source": {
        "name": "Software AG2"
      },
      "highlight": {
        "name": [
          "<em>Software</em> <em>AG2</em>"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "_source": {
        "name": "Op Software AG"
      },
      "highlight": {
        "name": [
          "Op <em>Software</em> <em>AG</em>"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "_source": {
        "name": "Op Software AG good software better"
      },
      "highlight": {
        "name": [
          "Op <em>Software</em> <em>AG</em> good <em>software</em> better"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "_source": {
        "name": "SoftwareRocks everytime"
      },
      "highlight": {
        "name": [
          "<em>SoftwareRocks</em> everytime"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**I read the highlight documentation on elasticsearch, but I cannot understand how the highlighting is performed. For the two examples above I expect only the matched token on the inverted index to be highlighted and not the whole word.
Can anyone help how to highlight only the passed value?**

**Update**

So, in seems that on [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/) website, the autocomplete on the server side is similar to my implementation. However it seems that they highlight the matched query on the client.
If they do like this, I started to think that there is not a proper solution to do it on ElasticSearch side, so I implemented the highlight feature on server side instead of on client side(as they seem to do).

My implementation on server side(using PHP) is:

```
public function search($term)
{
    $params = [
        'index' => $this->getIndexName(),
        'type' => $this->getIndexType(),
        'body' => [
            'query' => [
                'match' => [
                    'name' => $term
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $results = $this->client->search($params);

    $hits = $results['hits']['hits'];

    $data = [];

    $wrapBefore = '<strong>';
    $wrapAfter = '</strong>';

    foreach ($hits as $hit) {
        $data[] = [
            $hit['_source']['id'],
            $hit['_source']['name'],
            preg_replace("/($term)/i", "$wrapBefore$1$wrapAfter", strip_tags($hit['_source']['name']))
        ];
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Outputs what I aimed with this question:

[image]

I added a bounty to see if there is a solution at ElasticSearch level to achive what I described above.

Comment: have you tried double quoting ? like `"\"soft\""` I suspect is the might be the kind of search that you are doing there that might make the difference

Comment: Have you tried to [force source highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#_force_highlighting_on_source) by specifying `"force_source" : true`?

Comment: Also you might also want to see [Prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/prefix-query.html) for the "soft" example

Comment: @Val force_source option seems not to solve the issue. I keep receiving the same highlights

Comment: @gerosalesc Sorry, I do not want to search "soft" with quotes, just the word soft, or software ag. Regarding prefix query, it looks only for the first occurrence of soft, but if I have two two times software on the source it does not highlight it.  And for "software ag" for example, it does not match. Im looking for a full-text search on the "real" sense of it. And as far i can tell, prefix query is kinda bad in terms of performance for a large index.

Comment: @joaoalves - Would you be willing to share your solution? I am trying to fix the same issue. I want to have something similar to autocomplete so when searching my ES indexes the populated drop down has highlighted text for the characters that are matches and that sounds similar to what you did if i am correct? Thanks, Hopefully your solution can help me achieve a similar result :)

Answer (score 1):

As of now with latest version of elastic this is not possible as highligh documentation don't refer any settings or query for this. I checked elastic autocomplete example in browser console under xhr requests tab and found the response for "att" autocomplete response for keyword as follows.

```
url - https://search.elastic.co/suggest?q=att
    {
        "current_page": 1,
        "last_page": 4,
        "total_hits": 49,
        "hits": [
            {
                "tags": [],
                "url": "/elasticon/tour/2016/jp/not-attending",
                "section": "Elasticon",
                "title": "Not <em>Attending</em> - JP"
            },
            {
                "section": "Elasticon",
                "title": "<em>Attending</em> from Training - JP",
                "tags": [],
                "url": "/elasticon/tour/2016/jp/attending-training"
            },
            {
                "tags": [],
                "url": "/elasticon/tour/2016/jp/attending-keynote",
                "title": "<em>Attending</em> from Keynote - JP",
                "section": "Elasticon"
            },
            {
                "tags": [],
                "url": "/elasticon/tour/2016/not-attending",
                "section": "Elasticon",
                "title": "Thank You - Not <em>Attending</em>"
            },
            {
                "tags": [],
                "url": "/elasticon/tour/2016/attending",
                "section": "Elasticon",
                "title": "Thank You - <em>Attending</em>"
            },
            {
                "section": "Blog",
                "title": "What It's Like to <em>Attend</em> Elastic Training",
                "tags": [],
                "url": "/blog/what-its-like-to-attend-elastic-training"
            },
            {
                "tags": "Elasticsearch",
                "url": "/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/5.0/mapper-attachments-highlighting.html",
                "section": "Docs/",
                "title": "Highlighting <em>attachments</em>"
            },
            {
                "title": "<em>attachments</em> » email",
                "section": "Docs/",
                "tags": "Logstash",
                "url": "/guide/en/logstash/5.0/plugins-outputs-email.html#plugins-outputs-email-attachments"
            },
            {
                "section": "Docs/",
                "title": "Configuring Email <em>Attachments</em> » Actions",
                "tags": "Watcher",
                "url": "/guide/en/watcher/2.4/actions.html#configuring-email-attachments"
            },
            {
                "url": "/guide/en/watcher/2.4/actions.html#hipchat-action-attributes",
                "tags": "Watcher",
                "title": "HipChat Action <em>Attributes</em> » Actions",
                "section": "Docs/"
            },
            {
                "title": "Slack Action <em>Attributes</em> » Actions",
                "section": "Docs/",
                "tags": "Watcher",
                "url": "/guide/en/watcher/2.4/actions.html#slack-action-attributes"
            }
        ],
        "aggs": {
            "sections": [
                {
                    "Elasticon": 5
                },
                {
                    "Blog": 1
                },
                {
                    "Docs/": 43
                }
            ],
            "top_tags": [
                {
                    "XPack": 14
                },
                {
                    "Elasticsearch": 12
                },
                {
                    "Watcher": 9
                },
                {
                    "Logstash": 4
                },
                {
                    "Clients": 3
                },
                {
                    "Shield": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

But on frontend they are showing "att" only highlighted on in the autosuggest results. Hence they are handling the highlight stuff on browser layer.

Comment: Thanks for this. I checked the autocomplete on elastic website and yes, they seem to change the highlighted words on the browser layer, which seems strange for me. I was expecting a different approach, but well, if this is the way to go...